# How to get Ext JS source code for debugging?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, extjs

How to get Ext JS source code for debugging in browser ? Now I'm getting all ext js related code in single big file called ext-all-rtl-debug.js. Is it possible to get as separate files, example - separate file for Ext.form.field.ComboBox. I can find as an individual file in API docs but how to get them in browser debugging ?

Answer (score 0):

In `app.json`, there's the reference to `ext-all-rtl-debug.js`.

You can replace that reference with a reference to `ext.js` or `ext-debug.js` to get a file that only contains the bare minimum ExtJS code. All other code snippets will then be loaded individually.

Please note that this means the loading time of the debug version will increase drastically, in my case from seconds to minutes. The ext-all-rtl-debug.js is usually suitable enough for debugging, but YMMV.

Comment: Just remove that entry in the `js` array for the framework and it will load the files individually. No need to replace it.